# How to trigger container app for performing any long running task

Tags: azure, azure-functions, containers, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-apps

I'm bit new to developing in python and using containers in azure.
I want to run a simple python script for 30 mins using azure container app and I want to trigger deployment of azure container app using some other service.
Is possible to trigger azure container app deployment and run long running task using some other service ?

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Using logic apps you can create or deploy container app. Using logic app i have created container app based on [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-container-instances)

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. Here I have used recurrence trigger.
3. In create or updated container group, provided required details,
   [image]
   These reference links may help you for your requirement.
   [Link1](https://kohera.be/tutorials-2/running-python-scripts-on-azure-with-azure-container-instances/)
   [Link2](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/industry-blog/en-gb/technetuk/2020/02/27/running-python-scripts-on-demand-with-azure-container-instances-and-azure-logic-apps/)

Comment: Using logic apps we can  trigger azure container instance/ groups. I want to trigger azure container app either from azure functions or logic apps. The above document talks about triggering azure container instance. Please let me know if you have any idea about this

Comment: Sorry my bad. yes, you are right it's talking about container instance AFAIK in logic Apps it's not possible to trigger azure container app.